# Sum multiple columns

Tags: awk

I need to do multiple sums; my input file is:

```
DATE|NATION|CITY|FILES|REVENUE|FREQUENCY|INVESTMENT
20170807|USA|VIRGINIA|TIMES|1919150|1779|282075
20170807|USA|NYC|ROADS|92877|41|1599
20170808|USA|PENS|ROADS|133001|7|1
20170808|USA|NYC|TIMES|361625|1592|0
```

1. Sum $5 in every uniq of $1 (date)
2. sum $5 in every uniq where $4=="TIMES"
3. sum $5 in every uniq where $4=="ROADS"
4. sum $5 in every uniq where $4=="ROADS" and $3=="NYC"
5. arrange based on column $1

my expected output

```
DATE|REV|TIMES|ROADS|ROADS&NYC
20170807|2012027|1919150|92877|92877
20170808|494626|361625|133001|0
```

I only know how to sum based on 1 column

```
awk -F"|" '{FS=OFS="|"}{col[$1]+=$5} END {for (i in col) print i, col[i]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'[|]' 'NR>1             { I[$1]+=$5 }
    ($4=="TIMES")             { T[$1]+=$5 }
    ($4=="ROADS")             { R[$1]+=$5 }
    ($4=="ROADS" && $3=="NYC"){ RN[$1]+=$5 }
END{ print "DATE|REV|TIMES|ROADS|ROADS&NYC"
     for (x in I) printf"%d|%d|%d|%d|%d\n", x, I[x], T[x], R[x], RN[x]
}' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex ***gawk*** solution to reach the goal:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }NR==1{ next }{ sum[$1]+=$5 }
     $4=="TIMES"{ d[$1]["t"]+=$5 }
     $4=="ROADS"{ d[$1]["r"]+=$5 }$3=="NYC" && $4=="ROADS"{ d[$1]["r&n"]+=$5 }
     END{ print "DATE|REV|TIMES|ROADS|ROADS&NYC"; 
     for(i in d) print i, sum[i], int(d[i]["t"]), int(d[i]["r"]), int(d[i]["r&n"]) }' file
```

The output:

```
DATE|REV|TIMES|ROADS|ROADS&NYC
20170807|2012027|1919150|92877|92877
20170808|494626|361625|133001|0
```

Comment: it works, thanks alot. I wish I can learn faster in this forum. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple arrays. Just compose the indices on the fields, sum everything and return only the summed indices you want, adding 0 to make sure `NULL` fields are shown.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; print "DATE|REV|TIMES|ROADS|ROADS&NYC"}
    NR>1{rev[$1]+=$5; sum[$1$4]+=$5; sum[$1$4$3]+=$5}
    END{for (dt in rev) print dt, rev[dt], sum[dt"TIMES"]+0, sum[dt"ROADS"]+0, sum[dt"ROADSNYC"]+0}' file
```

It's also a bit more readable....

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
mlr --csv --fs pipe \
    reshape -s FILES,REVENUE then \
    put '$tmp=$ROADS; $REV=$ROADS+$TIMES' then \
    reshape -s CITY,tmp then \
    stats1 -a sum -g DATE -f REV,TIMES,ROADS,NYC then \
    unsparsify --fill-with 0 file.csv
```

This generates the following given the data in the question:

```
DATE|REV_sum|TIMES_sum|ROADS_sum|NYC_sum
20170807|2012027|1919150|92877|92877
20170808|494626|361625|133001|0
```

The first operation, a `reshape` operation, takes the values from the `FILES` field and generates new fields from these with the values from `REVENUE`. This gives us the following records (in three separate sets as some fields are missing for some records):

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | TIMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | VIRGINIA | 1779 | 282075 | 1919150 |

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | ROADS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | NYC | 41 | 1599 | 92877 |
| 20170808 | USA | PENS | 7 | 1 | 133001 |

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | TIMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170808 | USA | NYC | 1592 | 0 | 361625 |

The `put` operation calculates the `REV` field for each record by summing the `ROADS` and `TIMES` values (one of these will be missing in each record).  We also calculate a temporary value that will later be used to calculating the sum of the `ROADS` revenues for `NYC`. After the `put`, we have the following data:

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | TIMES | REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | VIRGINIA | 1779 | 282075 | 1919150 | 1919150 |

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | ROADS | tmp | REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | NYC | 41 | 1599 | 92877 | 92877 | 92877 |
| 20170808 | USA | PENS | 7 | 1 | 133001 | 133001 | 133001 |

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | TIMES | REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170808 | USA | NYC | 1592 | 0 | 361625 | 361625 |

The second `reshape` gives us a way to more easily calculate the `ROADS` sum for `NYC`:

| DATE | NATION | CITY | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | TIMES | REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | VIRGINIA | 1779 | 282075 | 1919150 | 1919150 |
| 20170808 | USA | NYC | 1592 | 0 | 361625 | 361625 |

| DATE | NATION | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | ROADS | REV | NYC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | USA | 41 | 1599 | 92877 | 92877 | 92877 |

| DATE | NATION | FREQUENCY | INVESTMENT | ROADS | REV | PENS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170808 | USA | 7 | 1 | 133001 | 133001 | 133001 |

Then we use the `stats1` command to calculate the sum for the required fields, grouped by `DATE`:

| DATE | REV_sum | TIMES_sum | ROADS_sum | NYC_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | 2012027 | 1919150 | 92877 | 92877 |

| DATE | REV_sum | TIMES_sum | ROADS_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170808 | 494626 | 361625 | 133001 |

And then we finally unsparsify this so that all records that lack fields present in other records have those fields added with a zero as the value:

| DATE | REV_sum | TIMES_sum | ROADS_sum | NYC_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20170807 | 2012027 | 1919150 | 92877 | 92877 |
| 20170808 | 494626 | 361625 | 133001 | 0 |